# Cannot open zip files

Tags: vbscript, zip

This seems like a question with an easy solution, but I searched the site (and web) for solution and I did not find any.

In order to open a zip file I'm using the following code:

```
  Set zipApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  zip_file_count = zipApp.NameSpace("c:\1.zip").Items.Count
  MsgBox zip_file_count
```

when c:\1.zip is an existing zip file (with one file inside).
So my expectations where to see a msg box with "1", instead I get "the system could not find the file specified" even that the file exist (if I try to do in windows Run> c:\1.zip it works)

I also use this code to open a zip I just created and still get the same error.

Is there something I am missing?

btw, I'm using windows XP is the operating system is somehow relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it works **IF** the following changes are made

```
set zip_file_count = zipApp.NameSpace("c:\1.zip").Items.Count
^^^
```

What you are retrieving is the count of files, not a object reference, so, this `set` is incorrect and should be removed.

BUT i did not get a *"the system could not find the file specified"* error but an *"object required"*.

**edited** under the assumption that the `.zip` file is accesible and not corrupt, the only way i have found to get the reported error has been to unregister the zip folder support. And the problem is corrected reregistering it again. So, you need the `zipfldr.dll` file present in your `%systemroot%\system32` folder and to register it with

```
regsvr32 "%systemroot%\system32\zipfldr.dll"
```

Comment: I've removed the set, still get the "the system could not find the file specified" error

Comment: +1 for the willingness to compromise your running system to help another person.

Comment: And it worked! Thanks!
I didn't even think about registration problem

Answer (score 0):

You won't see a message box with "1", but an "Object required" error, because zip_file_count should hold a number, not an object, so

```
set zip_file_count = zipApp.NameSpace("c:\1.zip").Items.Count
```

should be

```
zip_file_count = zipApp.NameSpace("c:\1.zip").Items.Count
```

As you didn't report this error, the code you run isn't the code you posted.

Without the Set and given an accessible .zip file, the code you posted 'works'. So double check "c:\1.zip" and its properties/rights.

Comment: I've removed the set, still get the "the system could not find the file specified" error, and I double checked the zip file, its there.

Comment: What about the access rights *for the user account your script runs under*? IIS? MapPath?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean, I run the script locally on a user with administrator access, and like I said, I can open and modify the file if I open it from the same location not in the script.

Comment: As both MCND and I (using Win XP) have verified, the script you posted 'works'. If you garantee that the .zip exists and is accessible, then the error is caused by another line in the program you didn't publish. Or: Your Shell.Application is broken.

Comment: I grantee that the .zip exists and is accessible and what I posted is the entire program.
how can I test if my "Shell.Application" is broken? I try the sane code only with "c:\" instead of "c:\1.zip" and it works (for the folder). 
Is there another way around to open\copy files to zip?